# How i can convert curl's incomming string to another charset with specialchars?

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding, iconv

Help me please with my problem.
I have a site on windows-1251 charset.
When i paste the string from clipboard into a input text form "**Tradición**" and press submit, i have needed result - $_POST['name'] = **Tradición**.. Then i make htmspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES, "") and get the string **Tradición**(Tradici&# 243;n) for inserting to MySQL.

**BUT!!!**

I'm getting a string via CURL from another site, which has utf-8 charset.
Needed string is: **Tradición**.
In windows-1251 there is not letter "ó" and i should doing iconv("utf-8", "cp1251//TRANSLIT", $newname).. Result is: **Tradici?n**. htmlspecialchars does not give needed result..
How i can get the string **Tradición** via CURL, help me please.

Need string: **Tradici&# 243;n**

Thank you in advance, guys..

Answer (score 0):

How about encode input string with urlencode function, this will produce this 'Tradici%C3%B3n'. Than make iconv, than urldecode.

Comment: Hey, it solved your problem? Some feed back will be appreciated :)